# populating the dropdown based on selection

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have to populate the tasks dropdown with data based upon the selection of project down. I have a Project model which has projects, A Task model which has tasks and a Projectsettings model which has the data as to which project has which tasks associated with it.

In my view when I select a particular project from the dropdown it has to show me the associated tasks in the task dropdown.

Currently in view I have this code for the **project dropdown:**

```
<%= hidden_field_tag "entries[id][]", entry.id %>
 <%= select_tag "entries[project_id][]",
options_for_select(active_projects([[""]]), entry.project_id || unspecified_project.id) %>
```

The active_projects method is in the helper which gets the active projects.

**For task dropdown:**

```
<%= select_tag "entries[task_id][]", options_from_collection_for_select([unspecified_task], 'id', 'name', entry.task_id || unspecified_task.id) + grouped_options_for_select(active_tasks, entry.task_id.to_s) %>
```

The active_tasks is a method in the helper which gets the active tasks currently.

**ProjectSettings model : has project_name and tasks column**

```
Class TimesheetProjectSettings < ActiveRecord::Base
unloadable

serialize :tasks, Array
end
```

how do I get the dropdown values in the tasks to be populated when I select a project using rails ? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You might give [this](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=rails+linked+dropdowns&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) a go. It looks like there could be some viable directions to head in.

Comment: http://blog.kate-travers.com/dynamic-duos-dependent-select-with-jquery-and-rails/  this link helped a lot!!!